# Xcode name issue

Tags: ios, xcode

I've just realised that I've created my app ID bundle indentifier with a lower case name, and I've set up my xcode project with the same name but with the first 2 letters in upper case, so for example my bundle indentifier is something like

```
com.mysite.my-game
```

But my xcode project name is...

```
My-Game
```

So I think xcode has used that to create my bundle indentifier, and the bundle indentifier is...

```
com.mysite.My-Game
```

So first question is, **does it make any difference?**

2nd question is, if it does, **how do I change the project name/bundle indentifier in xcode to be...**

```
my-game
```

i'e the same as the app ID version?

and 3rd, **what name is going to be displayed when the game is live on the app store**, because I would actually prefer...

```
My-Game
```

Comment: I wonder if there is any particular problem using a search at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation

Comment: Well done for a completely unhelpful comment. I've obviously searched the doc's, and read through answers on here, but none seem to address what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So first question is, does it make any difference?

Yes it does.

> 2nd question is, if it does, how do I change the project name/bundle
>   indentifier in xcode to be...

Simply edit your info.plist file, edit the `Bundle identifier` entry by removing the default containing `${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}` and enter the correct one you need.

In case you wish to keep Xcode generating your bundle identifier, change the `Product name` entry below `Packaging` within your `Build Settings`.

> 3rd, what name is going to be displayed when the game is live on the
>   app store, because I would actually prefer...

That will be determined once you submit your app. You may freely chose any name within iTunes Connect - no need for it to correlate with Bundle name or Bundle identifier.

Comment: But is that "PRODUCT_NAME" being drawn from the project's name? if it is, how do I change the projects name? I've tried but it just gives me an error. I'd rather keep everything generated from xcode than manually put in values.

Comment: For changing the PRODUCT_NAME, check your build-settings (Packaging) for the entry `Product name`.

Comment: Tried that, but it doesn't seem to let you change it. I've deleted the the line in the .plist file though and that seems to have saved, so that's something, thanks. Actually it's giving me 2 weird errors "'CFBundleSignature' is 'com.mysite.my-game', which can't be converted to a four-character code in MacRoman encoding (as needed for PkgInfo); using '????'" and Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'App-Info.plist'.

Comment: You need to watch out for removing entire key-value-pairs from that plist - that usually is not the way to go. You may however have edited the "wrong" part of your build-settings. There are two versions, the project specific and the target specific. The latter overwrites the former if written in bold characters.

Answer (score 1):

To make this warning go away, edit Info.plist file, and make sure the key *Bundle creator OS Type code* is not empty. If it is empty, you can use ????